# Meteor-Accounts: Redirect to another route and display a different template after signing in

Tags: meteor-accounts

Which is the best practice on how to redirect a user to a different layout template after a successful sign-in?  (i.e. Using the {{> loginButtons}} inclusion operator from accounts-ui and Iron.Router)

Comment: Please add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Accounts.onLogin(func)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) method and call [Iron Router's](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#using-redirects) `Router.go(/*url path*/)` method in the function you pass to your `Accounts.onLogin` call.

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer. For reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin